# How to fix Cannot read property 'maps' of null" on Quasar Vue Google Maps?

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

How can I solve this Cannot read property 'maps' of null", when I call initMap to center the map with this line of code,

```
const map = new this.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: this.property
      })
```

I already define this.google in compute also, but it doesn't work.
This is what i have done

```
    <template>
  <q-layout view="hhh lpr fff" class="main-layout">
    <q-page-container>
      <GmapMap
        id="map"
        ref="mapRef"
        :center="{lat:-7.250445, lng:112.768845}"
        :zoom="13"
        map-type-id="terrain"
        style="width: 1000px; height: 600px; margin-left:100px"
      >
        
      </GmapMap>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

export default {

  name: 'DefaultLayout',

  data () {
    return {
      mapName: "map",
      property: {
          lat: 1.28237,
          lng: 103.783098
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {
    google: VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi
  },
  mounted () {

    this.initMap();
  },
  methods: {
    initMap() {
      const map = new this.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: this.property
      })
      
    },
  },

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Computed property should be a [getter function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example). I think you don't need a computed property here. You can make everything in the `initMap` method, e.g.

```
   initMap() {
      if(VueGoogleMaps) {
      new VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: this.property
      })
   }
 }
```